# I am trying to write a loop that recaluclates an eigenvector each time I add a new eigenvector

Tags: r, for-loop, eigenvector

I am new to R.  I am currently trying to write a loop that will recalculate an eigenvector each time I add an additional eigenvector.  I then want the Goodness of fit test displayed for each calculation.
I was told to create a loop and set k=i.  I have tried every variation I know and cant get it to work.

I currently have this:

```
CMD<-cmdscale(data2,k=126,eig = TRUE)
for(i in 1:126)
 print(CMD$GOF)
```

but it returns **126** of the same value and it should be an incremental increasing value.

Comment: First off, your code as written does not run. You haven't provided any data, and your `for` loop has no braces. The following might help you move in the right direction: `for (i in 1:126) {cmd = cmdscale(dat, k=i); print(cmd$GOF)}`.

Comment: Thanks , your suggestion worked great